# Date Formatting Using moment.Js in node Application

Tags: node.js, momentjs

I am converting Date "2019-10-28T20:00:00.000Z" using moment.js as moment(date).format("MM/DD/YYYY").
the Date become "10/29/2019" from given date.
any Solution for that ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Checkout [moment.js parsing formats](https://momentjs.com/docs/#/parsing/special-formats/).

Basically: `moment("2019-10-28T20:00:00.000Z", moment.ISO_8601).format("MM/DD/YYYY")`

Comment: i don't want date to be change. it should be remain same after formatting.

Comment: 2019-10-28T20:00:00.000Z is UTC time - if you display it in Indian time (IST) it will be the 29th.

Comment: moment("2019-10-28T20:00:00.000Z").utc().format("MM/DD/YYYY")
this solution works for me.